# helm-M-x doesn't show initial list of candidates

Tags: emacs

After updating HELM and restarting Emacs it doesn't show a list of initial candidates. However, it shows them after you start typing. This is inconvenient as visual cues are lacking. Has anyone encountered and solved it?
[image]

[image]

My config is as simple as this:

```
(straight-use-package '(helm :type git :host github :repo "emacs-helm/helm"))
(use-package helm
  :config (helm-mode)
  :bind (("M-x" . helm-M-x)
         ("C-o" . helm-find-files)
         ("M-s s" . helm-projectile)
         ("s-a" . helm-ag)
     ("M-s M-s" . helm-projectile-switch-project)
     ("C-b" . helm-mini)
         :map helm-map
         ("<tab>" . helm-execute-persistent-action)
     ("C-i" . helm-select-action)
     ("M-k" . helm-next-line)
     ("M-i" . helm-previous-line)
     :map helm-find-files-map
     ("M-i" . helm-previous-line)
     ("M-k" . helm-next-line)
     :map helm-generic-files-map
     ("M-i" . helm-previous-line)
     ("M-k" . helm-next-line)
     ))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with Centaur-tabs, somehow it interfered with `Helm-M-x`. Disabling it helped. I didn't try to update it as I'm going to switch to the `tab-line-mode`. So I won't be testing the issue deeper it the moment. The important thing is Helm works as supposed now.